# react-dropzone: inspect files while dragging is active

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I have build a file upload component with drag-n-drop using `react-dropzone`.

I would like to inspect the files, that the user dragges onto the dropzone and do this **while** they are dragged (**before** they are dropped onto the dropzone).

I tried this:

```
<Dropzone
  accept="application/pdf"
  onDrop={this.handleDragDrop}
>
  {({ draggedFiles, isDragActive, isDragReject, acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles }) => {
    if (isDragActive) {
      ... inspect files here (before dropping)
    }
  }}
</Dropzone>
```

But non of `draggedFiles`, `acceptedFiles` and `rejectedFiles` has any value.

Am I missing something here... ?

---

**EDIT:**

To make my question more clear:

I want to do a validation of the files, before the user drops them to the `dragzone`. The validation by passing mimetypes to the `accept` property is not enougth in my scenario:

1. user is dragging files over the `dragzone` and `onDragOver` is fired
2. now the files are inspected and the `dragzone` is updated to show a message `files are ok` or `files not ok`, so the user gets this information **BEFORE** he drops the files
3. user is dropping the files and `onDrop` is triggered

Answer (score 3):

## Short answer

AFAIK You can't

## Long answer

Let's see the following code:

```js
<Dropzone 
  accept="image/*,application/pdf" 
  maxSize={5000000}
  onDrop={this.onDrop}
  onDragEnter={this.onDragEnter}
>
  {({getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragAccept, isDragReject }) => {
    let classes = 'form-control'
    let placeholder = <p>Drag files here</p>;
    if (isDragAccept) {
      classes = `${classes} border-success bg-light`;
      placeholder = <p className="text-success">Drop files now</p>;
    } 
    if (isDragReject) {
      classes = `${classes} border-danger bg-light`;
      placeholder = <p className="text-danger">Some files are not allowed</p>
    }
    return (
      <div {...getRootProps()} style={{ height: '100px' }} className={classes}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        {placeholder}
      </div>
    );
  }}
</Dropzone>
```

This snippet changes the style of the dropzone if the file to be dropped meets some requirements (any image type or pdf file and that is less than 5MB of size). If we drag any file over the dropzone the values of `acceptedFiles` and `rejectedFiles` are both an empty array. The value of `draggedFiles` is an array of [DataTransferItems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem) which give us the `kind` and `type` of the file being dragged, for example `{kind: "file", type: "application/pdf"}`.

At this point the values of `isDragAccept` and `isDragReject` are setted based on the *type of the file*. So, if we drag an image or a pdf file the value `isDragAccept` is set to `true`, the text `Drop files now` will be shown in the dropzone its border will be colored according the class `border-success`. But the same will occur if the file is greater than 5MB! Why? This is because we cannot read the file before the drop event.

Let see the event handlers:

```js
onDrop = (acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles, event) => {
  console.log(event.dataTransfer.items)
  console.log(event.dataTransfer.files)
}

onDragEnter = (event) => {
  console.log(event.dataTransfer.items)
  console.log(event.dataTransfer.files)
}
```

The drag events give us a [dataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent/dataTransfer) property which is a [DataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) object. Here we have two properties that are important to us:

- `DataTransfer.items`

  This is a [DataTransferItemList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItemList) object which give us a list of [DataTransferItems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem). It's the same object in the `draggedFiles` array and we can access this in both handlers: onDragEnter and onDrop.
- `DataTransfer.files`

  This holds a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) object of the drag operation, but *it's empty in the Drag events* so we can access it only after the drop. For example, in the previous code if we drag and drop some file we get this output for the console log for the events showed:

```
FileList {length: 0} // dragEnter event
FileList {0: File(30299626), length: 1} // drop event
```

If we access the element 0 of the File list after the drop we get:

```
File(30299626) {name: "python_101.pdf", lastModified: 1549327543709, lastModifiedDate: Mon Feb 04 2019 21:45:43 GMT-0300 (Chile Summer Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 30299626, …}
```

Thus, we can only access data of the file **After** the drop event.

Comment: 1. The files property of `DataTransfer` objects can only be accessed from within the `drop` event. For all other events, the files property will be empty — because its underlying data store will be in a protected mode. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/files

2. Relying on the `type` is not reliable, MIME types are deprecated. Source: https://react-dropzone.js.org/#notes and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MimeType

Answer (score 1):

do this (React):

```
  onDragOverHandle(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.dataTransfer.items[0])
  }
```

you can get drag target type, like :

`{kind: "file", type: "image/png"}` or `{kind: "file", type: "video/mp4"}`

then you can do something you want to do.

hope to help you ~

Answer (score 1):

as @Jay lu sayied, you can do using something like this:

```
const onDragEnter = (event) => {
    const fileType = event.dataTransfer.items[0].type;
    const validTypes = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg'];
    const valitate = validTypes.some(types => types === fileType);
    !valitate && setDanger(true);
  }

const onDragLeave = (event) => {
    setDanger(false);
  }

<Dropzone
        onDrop={ onDrop }
        accept='image/jpeg, image/png, image/jpg'
        maxSize={500000}
        onDragEnter={onDragEnter}
        onDragLeave={onDragLeave}
      >
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to have init your state with : `this.state = { files: [] }` and handle drop files in function : `onDrop(files) { // do stuff with files... }`

This is an example extract from the doc https://react-dropzone.js.org/:

```
class Basic extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { files: [] }
 }

 onDrop(files) {
   this.setState({
     files
   });
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <section>
    <div className="dropzone">
      <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)}>
        <p>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.</p>
      </Dropzone>
    </div>
    <aside>
      <h2>Dropped files</h2>
      <ul>
        {
          this.state.files.map(f => <li key={f.name}>{f.name} - {f.size} bytes</li>)
        }
      </ul>
    </aside>
  </section>
);
}}
```

Comment: thanks, but this handles files **after** they have been dropped. I want to handle them **before** this.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? Check the file type ?

Comment: If you want to prevent the files types, you can use this : 
    `<Dropzone accept=".jpeg,.png" >`

Comment: I have updated my question to (hopefully) make it more clear

Comment: Your `files are ok` and `files are not ok` are there to check the file content ? So, you want to check the content of your files ?

Comment: yes, I would like to have access to the files BEFORE the files are dropped, e.g. in `onDragOver`