# Drag & Drop from email to a javascript component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a component to drag & drop files and I was wondering if it is possible to drag & drop files directly from email (e.g. Outlook). 
I now this is supposed to work on the new versions of Chrome and Safari. 
But my point is, is it possible develop some way to control this, using JS or HTML?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you are trying to do I refer you to this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997587/react-dropzone-inspect-files-while-dragging-is-active)

As this discussion was not found via the search function in the duplicate flagging form, I posted it here.